# How do I implement an adapter for my listview in fragment

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I´m trying to create a `ListView` in my tab which extends a `Fragment`. I´m getting an error when I try to use `android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1`.

Here is the code:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1); //<-- get error here.
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTab1);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to the ArrayAdapter needs to be a `Context` and using `this` (the `Fragment`) is not one. Use the `Activity` hosting the `Fragment` instead. Also, don't forget to actually set the adapter on your `listView` and at some point add data to the adapter.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTab1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time please post the error you get. "An error" could be anything. However in this case George Mulligan is probably correct.